# InstallShield LE installer will not run on windows 8 tablet

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-8.1, installshield-le

i am using VisualStudio 2013, with InstallShield LE 2013.
my program is WPF desktop application, based on .Net 4.5.

installer runs with no issue on windows 7, windows 8 and windows 8.1 standard machines.

i am now trying to run it on a tablet, running windows 8.1. 
when running the installer, it starts nicely, but after a short while i get an error saying:
"This installation package is not supported by this processor type"

the tablet has Intel Atom processor.
the system type says: 32 bit OS, x64 based processor.

when simply copy the application to this machine, it runs with no issues.

according to something i found on google, i tried to change the target CPU of the project to x86, but this did not help.

can someone please help?

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:** the VisualStudio 2010 installer runs with no issues! Looks like InstallShield is an downgrade in this sense.

Comment: Have you tried not to install the application just copy and paste the executable?

Comment: Yes, the application runs with no issues.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.